# git not honoring core.sharedRepository=group (file read-only after git push)

Tags: git

I have a shared git repo on a local network. Developers clone the repo, make changes locally, and then push changes.  Access to the shared repo is via ssh, with developers using personal login credentials.  All users have the same primary group, which is the same group on all files/directories in the repo. I have used find commands to ensure all directories are 775 and all files are 664.  The repo config has core.sharedRepository = group.  The repo was created with git init --bare.  The shared settings (file permissions and core.sharedRepository=group) were setup after the repo was created, cloned, and several changes were pushed.

The issue I am seeing is that after a push, a modified file will change permissions from -rw-rw-r--(664) to -r--r--r-- (444).  A subsequent push of that same file will fail due to the changed permissions.

I can clean up the repo using find commands listed below but it would be nice if I could keep this from occuring in the first place.

```
find repoDir -type f -not -writable -exec chmod 664 {} \;
find repoDir -type d -not -writable -exec chmod 775 {} \;
```

**Question: Why is git not honoring the core.sharedRepository setting?**

*Server repo is running git 1.8.4.2*

*Client repo running gitbash 1.8.0 or egit 3.0.3*

**Example gitbash output:**

Edit file and push (Success)

```
developer@workstation /repo (dev)
$ git push
developer@server password:
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 366 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To ssh://developer@server/git/repo
   35b5daa..22b443a  dev -> dev
```

Edit file and push (fail)

```
developer@workstation /repo (dev)
$ git push
developer@server password:
Counting objects: 7, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 368 bytes, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: insufficient permission for adding an object to repository database ./objects
remote: fatal: failed to write object
error: unpack failed: unpack-objects abnormal exit
To ssh://developer@server/git/repo
 ! [remote rejected] dev -> dev (unpacker error)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://developer@server/git/repo'

developer@workstation /repo (dev)
$
```

**Update:**

I just repeated the example and did not get the failure - looks like this time git put the changes into a new file under objects. The new file has read only permissions which I did not expect, but the push at least worked.

Comment: Please give an example of push commands that "fail". 

What you describe seems correct behaviour: someone pushes revision X, git stores it as read-only files (which, by the way, you shouldn't be messing with), and nobody else can push revision X ever again.

Comment: Question updated with git bash output

Comment: Needs more info. It's expected that object files are created read-only as Git's database is an immutable object store. I suspect that the permissions on the `.git/objects` are still not correct despite your `find` command. If I understand correctly `-writable` only applies to the user running `find` so if a directory is owned by the current user but not group writable the chmod wouldn't have been executed. Really there's no reason not to simply do `-type d` alone for the second find command.

Comment: I was expecting the files under the objects/xx/ sub directories in the git server repo to keep their 664 permissions with the sharedRepository config item set to group. Is it normal for these files to reset to 444 after a push in a shared reposititory?

Answer (score 2):

Note that when creating a file, its access right bits will be subject for *masking* with the current process's `umask`, so if your server-side `git` process runs with umask `077`, "group" and "others" triplets of bits will always be 0 no matter which access mode the process set for the file when it called `open(2)`.

I'm not sure Git does not try to do explicit `chmod()`s (there are pretty few calls to `chmod(2)` in Git's code, and they do not seem to be related to handling push operation.

Grepping the Git code base for `sharedRepository` yields that the only place this setting is read is the `git_config_perm` function in `setup.c`, and then the only place it's called is the `builtin/init-db.c` file which, I reckon, gives a hint that this setting does only affect the creation of the database (`git init`, that is).

I'm not sure where to follow from there, just sharing my discoveries.

Comment: The `core.sharedRepository` setting affects most mutating operations. It's also called from `check_repository_format` in `setup.c` which is a precursor to most operations. (See `calc_shared_perm` and `adjust_shared_perm` in `path.c`.)

Comment: Do I need to ensure each user has "umask 002" in their ~/.[shell]rc file to have updates to my server repo have 664 permissions?

Answer (score 0):

If you enable core.sharedRepository=group, ensure the connected user is a member of that group.  In our case, we use 'git' user.

Comment: I am currently not able to reproduce the issue, but I will keep your suggestion in mind if I ever come across it in the future.